# `RegisterDragDrop` returns S_OK, but no calls to the method DragEnter

Tags: windows, delphi, api

I'm facing this problem in Windows 7. First I define a class which implements `IDropTarget`. Then I use `RegisterDragDrop` with a handle to a control placed in a window of my application. The `RegisterDragDrop` returns `S_OK` but when I drag&drop a link from `Mozilla FireFox` to the control, there is no call to `DragEnter` nor any other function of the `IDropTarget` implementing object. I'm so exhausted don't know what to do.
Thanks in advance

P.S: I just found out that when I run my app as administrator, this problem happens!
When I just run the application normally, everything works fine! (Perhaps does it have anything to do with changing messages filter?)

Comment: That will teach you not to run the IDE as admin.

Comment: @David: Exactly, IDE should work well enough without being run as admin.

Comment: @Javid It does. I never run it admin. Even old versions. Like Delphi 6.

Comment: Just ran into the same problem. You cannot drag from non-admin into admin applications.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Hey this just came to my mind; sometimes we need to run IDE as admin; like when the app itself requires Administrator privileges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your code is correct and you've implemented your side correctly; if you're developing on Windows Vista or Windows 7, make sure you're running the application at the same privilege level as Mozilla. If you're developing in the IDE running as administrator, but run Mozilla Firefox as the logged in user, then they cannot communicate through drag-drop.

If that isn't the case, then you can try dragging files from Windows explorer to make sure your code is working correctly. It could be that Mozilla Firefox isn't using Microsoft's Ole Drag and drop subsystem correctly or at all.

Comment: Seems true. Just now, I tested it and found the results proving your answer. (Tested it by launching Firefox with administrator privileges)